# Syntax highlighting doesn't work on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

Like the title says:

```python
from itertools import permutations

def number_of_clicks(l):
    bets = list(l)
    clicks = 0
    state = [[False, None], [False, None], [False, None], [False, None], [False, None]]
    while bets:
        next = bets.pop(0)
        for s, n in zip(state, next):
            if s[0] != n[0]:
                clicks += 1 # checkbox
                s[0] = n[0]
            if s[1] != n[1] and n[1] is not None:
                clicks += 2 # dropdown
                s[1] = n[1]

    return clicks

bets = map(lambda l: map(lambda p: [bool(p), p], l), input())

result = min(permutations(bets), key=number_of_clicks)

for l in result: print map(lambda e: e[1], l)
print number_of_clicks(result)
```

(taken from [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7535/45941) Sandbox post)

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
```

Has no effect.

Syntax highlighting would be very useful for the Sandbox. It works [on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300633/how-to-format-a-link-within-a-code-block), so why not here?

Comment: Interestingly, it works in the Android app.

Comment: @MartinBüttner This becomes less interesting when you realize that the Android app uses the "default" syntax highlighting colors for every single code block (i.e. it completely ignores syntax highlighting comments and *never* uses language-specific highlighting). :P

Comment: Blame the fact that meta still has MathJax? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Now that meta no longer has MathJax, this bug still exists. Can anyone confirm whether syntax highlighting is switched on for meta?

Answer (score 14):

No idea why this wasn't on already; guessing we just forgot.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this!

Answer (score 9):

I assume everyone is in favour of syntax highlighting being possible on meta, but I'm adding an answer just so people can indicate either way with voting.

MathJax was mentioned as a potential cause of syntax highlighting not working, but MathJax has since been removed from meta, ruling this out as the cause. I suspect that syntax highlighting is simply switched off on meta. If so, I'd like to see it switched back on.